# How do i make two or more row long tables fit inline bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i want to layout two tables such that they don't fill the page and overflow to the next line using bootstrap and css. The 1st table with `max-width:60%` and second `max-width:40%`. It should be such that i can scroll on the `x-axis` and on the `y-axis` of each table. [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iwo7.jpg)

i have tried using the `max-width` property but the table seem to be overflowing to the next line

```
<div id="Customers" class=" jumbotron tabcontent bg-light">
    <h3>CUSTOMERS</h3>
    <table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0"
  max-width="60%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>    

<table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0"
  max-width="40%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>    


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.scroll {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div id="Customers" class=" jumbotron tabcontent bg-light">
    <h3>CUSTOMERS</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-8 scroll">
        <table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm  " cellspacing="0" max-width="60%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Tiger</td>
              <td>Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011/04/25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
              <td>5421</td>
              <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Garrett</td>
              <td>Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011/07/25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
              <td>8422</td>
              <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2009/01/12</td>
              <td>$86,000</td>
              <td>1562</td>
              <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>2012/03/29</td>
              <td>$433,060</td>
              <td>6224</td>
              <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi</td>
              <td>Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
              <td>5407</td>
              <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brielle</td>
              <td>Williamson</td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012/12/02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
              <td>4804</td>
              <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class=" col col-md-4 scroll">
        <table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0" max-width="40%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Tiger</td>
              <td>Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011/04/25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
              <td>5421</td>
              <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Garrett</td>
              <td>Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011/07/25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
              <td>8422</td>
              <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2009/01/12</td>
              <td>$86,000</td>
              <td>1562</td>
              <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>2012/03/29</td>
              <td>$433,060</td>
              <td>6224</td>
              <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi</td>
              <td>Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
              <td>5407</td>
              <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brielle</td>
              <td>Williamson</td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012/12/02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
              <td>4804</td>
              <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can adjust the height and width to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to modify your HTML and don't mind using `display:grid` and `display:contents`, to allow your table to overflow, you might do :
*https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzKQvOQ*

```css
#dtHorizontalVerticalExample,
#dtHorizontalVerticalExampleBis {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, auto);
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* id can be used only once */

#dtHorizontalVerticalExampleBis {
  max-width: 40%;
}


/* cells will become direct child of the grid system set on table */

thead,
tbody,
tfooter,
tr {
  display: contents;
}


/* OPTIONNAL KEEP headers on sight */


/* keep headers and name sticky */

thead th,
tbody td:first-child,
tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  background: white;
}

thead th {
  top: 0;
}

tr th:first-child,
tr th:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

tr :first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

tr :nth-child(2) {
  left: 3.8em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="Customers" class="d-flex flex-wrap jumbotron tabcontent bg-light">
  <h3 class="w-100">CUSTOMERS</h3>
  <table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm m-0" cellspacing="0" max-width="60%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett</td>
        <td>Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
        <td>8422</td>
        <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton</td>
        <td>Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
        <td>1562</td>
        <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric</td>
        <td>Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
        <td>6224</td>
        <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi</td>
        <td>Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
        <td>5407</td>
        <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle</td>
        <td>Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
        <td>4804</td>
        <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="dtHorizontalVerticalExampleBis" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm m-0" cellspacing="0" max-width="40%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett</td>
        <td>Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
        <td>8422</td>
        <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton</td>
        <td>Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
        <td>1562</td>
        <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric</td>
        <td>Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
        <td>6224</td>
        <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi</td>
        <td>Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
        <td>5407</td>
        <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle</td>
        <td>Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
        <td>4804</td>
        <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```

*inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WVXPNP*

Note : **id** can only used once .

i added a few bootstrap classes to add the flex behavior on

- `#Customers` : `d-flex flex-wrap`
- and `w-100` to `h3`

---

```
<div id="Customers" class="d-flex flex-wrap jumbotron tabcontent bg-light">
  <h3 class="w-100">CUSTOMERS</h3>
```

---

mind for the next few months : https://caniuse.com/#search=contents before making use of `display:contents`

Comment: when i scroll on the `x axis` the **First Name** and **Last Name** are not moving idk if that was intentionally or by design.

Comment: @xaander1 it is, look at the comments in the CSS and remove was is about "sticky" if you do not need this behavior ;)